# Operating system not found and I can't access the BIOS

Tags: operating-systems

Trying to fix an old laptop just for some experience. The operating system is not found and I cannot get into the BIOS. Any help on how to fix this would be great. Thanks.

[Click to open image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQnGx.jpg)

[Click to open image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Cn3l.jpg)

Comment: Your boot storage device is not detected.  This is evident by the fact it's attempting to failover to a PXE boot.  Replace the storage device and reinstall the OS.

Comment: Consult your laptop manual to find the correct key sequence to enter BIOS. Typical keys were Delete, F2, F8 and F12 and depend on your system. As mentioned by Ramhound "Operating system not found" means that your hard drive is damaged or corrupted.

Comment: If the laptop has a CD/DVD drive, you can also try to boot from any Linux install/live CD like Ubuntu or Puppy Linux (small image that fits on CD). In many cases the laptop tries to bott from CD if it doesn't find an OS on teh HDD.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. I'll get working on it and I'll report back and give yous an update. Thanks again.